# Can jQuery convert ASCII and Unicode characters?

Tags: jquery, mysql, unicode, ascii

We have some ASCII and Unicode characters which we want users to use when they are imputing text into a Form’s text and textarea fields.

For example,

```
$SpecialCharacters = array(
    'single quotes'=>'&#039;',
    'double quotes'=>'&#034;',
    'copyright'=>'&#169;',
    'registered'=>'&#174;',
    'trademark'=>'&#8482;',
);
```

We are using jQuery UI Drag and Drop to move the selected non-standard character from the toolbar to the input field. That works fine.

However, when the data is saved to the MySQL database (using PHP) and returned, the non-standard characters return in a malformed encoding.

- User inputs: `bill.onthebeach™`
- Returned page displays: `bill.onthebeachâ¢`

Everything is UTF-8 encoded.

So I'm thinking this should solve the problem:

- User inputs: `bill.onthebeach&#8482;`
- Returned page displays: `bill.onthebeach™`

The question is, Is there a jQuery function or plug-in that will convert non-standard characters to their encoded forms?

```
 ™ => &#8482;
```

Or, Does the problem lie elsewhere? If so, what’s the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> The question is, Is there a jQuery function or plug-in that will convert non-standard characters to their encoded forms?

You say “non-standard characters” but you actually mean “HTML character references”. Anyway, you can achieve what you want by [using the *he* JavaScript library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he):

```
he.encode('bill.onthebeach™');
// → 'bill.onthebeach&#x2122;'

he.decode('bill.onthebeach&#x2122;');
// → 'bill.onthebeach™'

he.decode('bill.onthebeach&#8482;');
// → 'bill.onthebeach™'
```

However, it seems the root of the problem lies elsewhere – there’s no point in using `he` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Javascript is always UTF-8. And this is a standard you can’t change. I wasted a lot of time using PHP to change the encoding of strings for older pages I work on, then I found out that you just need to set your MySQL connection to `utf8` and your HTML page to `<meta charset="UTF-8">`.

As long as you have those two settings set **and** your characters look fine in your HTML, you should be fine, no matter what.

I guess that it’s either your MySQL connection or your HTML page that is missing the `utf8` setting. Also, if you have these settings it doesn’t matter at all which collation your database fields use.

Comment: thanks.. our settings look like this... on the page...<meta charset="utf-8" />  ... and in DB (PhpMyAdmin ) - utf8_unicode_ci...  which does not fixed the issue illustrated above....

Comment: @BillWarren. Having the page and the database in UTF-8 is no good if the database *connection* is not also in UTF-8. See "[UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-throughhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)".

Comment: @TRiG yes, the database collation does not even matter. if you got a `latin_general_ci` collation somewhere in your database then `MySQL` will do all the work for you, als long as your connection is set to `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys...

Here's the basics of what works... the long version is too specific to our purposes to be useful..

1. TRiG and others are right... UTF-8 'all the way'... means 'all the way'...   DB and tables are set to - UTF8_unicode_ci
2. However, if you do that and this in your php --

   $data = utf8_encode($data);

The special characters are going to display "garbled"... so don't do both...

3. The jQuery draggable / droppable Object 'ui'.... does give us options to do things with special characters on the page, like search and replace ...  once you've located this...

   var char = ui['helper']['prevObject'][0]['firstChild']['data']

After that it's all full-speed straight ahead...

We've got it working smooth for html, ascii and unicode special characters.